# How to display the values of array in textbox?

Tags: html, ruby

I have a text box where i have to display the array values that i get from api and the problem is,
I have used like this

```
<input name="f" type="text" id="f" value=entries.f>
```

and i get the value as ["V"] incase of a single value and ["V", incase of multiple values so how can i display the array values like V, N in a textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you

```
 <input name="f" type="text" id="f" value="<%= entries.f %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="f" type="text" id="f" value="<%= entries.f %>">
```

This might help if you're using Rails with ERB